# HTML add bootstrap check inside input readonly

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I'm using bootstrap inside of my app on which I have a readonly input where I need to add checkmark inside of it. I tried to add simple `<input readonly type="text" id="kyc_status" class="form-control" value="Success">` but this won't work. Below is my HTML structure:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <form>
      <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="kyc_status" class="form-label">
            KYC Status
          </label>
          <input readonly type="text" id="kyc_status" class="form-control" value="Success">
          <i class="bi bi-check"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

So now it produces me:

[image]

How to put this checkmark inside of the input on the left ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.input-group`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/input-group/) and adjust styling of `.input-group-text` for your needs.
Below, I have added `.border-end-0`, `.bg-transparent`, and `.pe-0` to the `.input-group-text` and `.border-start-0` to the `input.form-control`.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <form>
      <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="kyc_status" class="form-label">
            KYC Status
          </label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-text border-end-0 bg-transparent pe-0"><i class="bi bi-check"></i></span>
            <input readonly type="text" id="kyc_status" class="form-control border-start-0" value="Success">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use position absolute property on checked icon and move it over the input field.

steps
**wrap input element and icon tag in one division with style property positions relative.**

then
for **input use** below property
**padding-left 20px**

then
for **icon use** below properties

**position absolute**

**left 10px - adjust according your inputs field size**

**top 5px - adjust according your inputs field size**

Answer (score 0):

I put both in a div tag and then gave the `position`.

`Note:` I have given color, width and height to the icon tag so that it can be seen. For testing.

You can use the following code. The style is also written.

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <form>
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="kyc_status" class="form-label">
                        KYC Status
                    </label>
                    <div class="pos">
                        <input readonly type="text" id="kyc_status" class="form-control" value="Success">
                        <i class="bi bi-check"></i>
                    </div>
                    <style>
                        .pos {
                            position: relative;
                        }

                        .bi-check {
                            width: 5px;
                            height: 4px;
                            background: red;
                            position: absolute;
                            top: 50%;
                            left: 3px;
                        }
                    </style>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

`Exactly like this:`

[image]

Comment: You're overriding bootstrap class here. I don't wanna have a dot but bootstrap checkmark instead.

Comment: I have written that the styling is to be seen, you can remove the three lines of width, height and background so that the icon will be displayed for you. `remove 3 line =   width: 5px;   height: 4px;   background: red;`

Comment: Still it's not what I meant - https://imgur.com/a/VrU1clT even when I play around with it and changed `top: 20%` it's oddly close to the input value https://imgur.com/jkfLRvq

Comment: I understand. You must give `padding-left:5px;` to the input tag at least 5px.  Test and see if it works??